# Unable to locate package python3-rosdep

Tags: ros-noetic, linux

I am trying to build ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 23.04 and python 3.11.4 from source. [Referring to the offical ROS documentation](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Source).

Step 1: Installing bootstrap dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-rosdep python3-rosinstall-generator python3-vcstools python3-vcstool build-essential
```

Gives the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-rosdep
E: Unable to locate package python3-vcstool
```

Step 2: For this, the documentation asks to add the packages.ros.org debian repository to apt source lists: [click here](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

I tried the above step and it was executed without producing any error.

But, I am still getting the same error when I tried Step 1 after Step 2 again.

Also, after step 2 when I run:

```
sudo apt update
```

It says:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease               
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease            
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lunar InRelease                       
Hit:6 https://mirror.mwt.me/shiftkey-desktop/deb any InRelease
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lunar Release                      
404  Not Found [IP: 2605:bc80:3010::134 80] 
Get:8 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-
onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04./InRelease [1,604 B]
Reading package lists... Done        
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When I visited to [ROS packages repository](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/), I couldn't see the the folder for Ubuntu 23.04 (lunar), does it mean that there is no package available yet for Ubuntu 23.04?

I haven't installed ROS from source before, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I suggest installing from the source, as you mentioned, and then reporting the errors/issues here. In that way, once we know the problem, it would be easy to find a solution. Thanks for your kind cooperation.

Comment: Please move all your comments to the question and modify your query including the title accordingly. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: There aren't any pre-built noetic packages for 23.04 on packages.ros.org, I don't think any of those 'Ubuntu install of ROS Noetic' instructions are what you want- what happens if you undo that change to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list, run apt update, and follow just the 'Installing from source' instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> E: Unable to locate package python3-rosdep
>
> E: Unable to locate package python3-vcstool

For these two packages, please install the following ones:

```
sudo apt install python3-rosdep2
sudo apt install python3-vcstools
```

I just tried it on Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar) and found them working!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but faced the same error, can you see my updated question.

Comment: As I said, both of the above packages are tested on Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar) and found working. Surprisingly, in your updated question, you are still installing old packages such as `python3-rosdep` and `python3-vcstool`. BTW, I found following links that could assist and provide some ideas for ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 23.04: [1](https://answers.ros.org/question/399664/will-ros-noetic-support-ubuntu-2204/), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/yrzqmt/ros_noetic_on_ubuntu_2204/?rdt=58062), and [3](https://answers.ros.org/question/402081/build-ros-noetic-in-ubuntu-2204/)

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#noetic-ninjemys-may-2020-may-2025), ROS Noetic is officially only targeting Ubuntu 20.04.

I never build ROS Noetic from sources on ubuntu 23.04, but
recently I build it on Ubuntu 22.04.
All the necessary steps are documented at the following blog post [Building ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 22.04](https://medium.com/@lukas_reisinger/building-ros-noetic-on-ubuntu-22-04-b3ca676c63e7).

Maybe this helps!